# Alert makes polyline on map display correctly! Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm reading a collection of lat/long from xml file and plotting as markers on a google map. Additional to this I join the markers with polylines based on the "flight coordinates example".

My problem is that I need to have an alert("anything") before the polylines are drawn, otherwise the markers doesn't display on map. I suspect it has to do with the loading of the map, but have no idea how to get past it? have tried setinterval, created a busy loop but does not solve my problem. Any assistance would be appreciated. Also, apologies if code does not display in one block

```
  function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://xxx.kmz');
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);

    var flightPlanCoordinates = new Array()

    downloadUrl("incident/breadCrumb.xml" + "?dummy=" + Math.random(), function (data) {
        var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

            var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
            var inspector = markers[i].getAttribute("inspector");
            var gpsDateTime = markers[i].getAttribute("gpsDateTime");
            var gpsLat = markers[i].getAttribute("gpsLat");
            var gpsLong = markers[i].getAttribute("gpsLong");
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(gpsLat, gpsLong);
            var marker = createMarker(id, inspector, gpsDateTime, gpsLat, gpsLong, latlng);
             flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(gpsLat, gpsLong);

        }
    });


alert("Data Ready") 
/// This is where the problem is, when I uncomment this alert the polylines do not show, 
///when it is in place it works??? WTF?

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
   }


function createMarker(id, inspector, gpsDateTime, gpsLat, gpsLong, latlng) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latlng, map: map });
    //      

    var contentString = '<div id="content" style="width:250px; height:250px; vertical-align: top; overflow: scroll;">' +
    '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; width:300px;">' +

   '<td >ID</td><td >' + id + '</td></tr>' +
  '<tr><td >inspector</td><td >' + inspector + '</td></tr>' +
  '<tr><td >gpsDateTime</td><td >' + gpsDateTime + '</td></tr>' +
  '<tr><td >gpsLat</td><td >' + gpsLat + '</td></tr>' +
  '<tr><td >gpsLong</td><td >' + gpsLong + '</td></tr>' +
   '</div>';

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString, maxWidth: 600 });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
}
```

Comment: You're treating an asynchronous interface as if it were synchronous. The "flightPath" stuff needs to be **inside** the callback to the "downloadUrl" function, because that's where you **know** that the stuff has been fetched.

Comment: Bang Bang!, 100 points! Thx pointy, why would it have worked with the alert in place though?

Comment: The `alert()` call halts the progress through the code, but it doesn't prevent the HTTP request from completing in the background. By the time you hit "Ok", the data is there. If the server were having a bad day, it might still fail even with the `alert()` if you closed it quickly.

Comment: is there a way to select your answer as correct? Or allocate points? sorry newbie

Comment: Thx, Appreciate your help!

Comment: I did it as a comment because this is an extremely common pitfall to newcomers, and I was too lazy to write a thorough answer :)